# Windows 7 batch: Change to program folder before starting program

Tags: windows-7, windows, batch

My program opens nicely with a Windows 7 shortcut. I want that in a batch file.
Contents of shortcut [full path] copied into *.bat opens program minus needed hidden parameters.

I tried preceding with "CD" and "CD /d" to folder, but no folder change. Manually changing to program folder, and copy of *.bat, then program works.

The CD does work in a command-prompt box.

Your posts about "CD /D %~dp0" don't teach me enough.

Comment: Does the path name contain spaces, and if so, are you surrounding it in quotes?

Answer (score 0):

Well, try that:

```
cd %programfiles%
```

Or:

```
cd "c:\program files (x86)"
```

Or:

```
cd "c:\program files"
```

Remember that if you are running from a different drive, you must change it in the batch, simply writing that before or after cd command:

```
c:
```